Trouble importing RSA-PSS key in NodeJS using subtle.importKey
I'm trying to import a private key to sign an XML file in NodeJS.
To sign the XML, I'm using xmldsigjs which requires the key to be passed in a CryptoKey object that is obtained by crypto.subtle.importKey.
In my understanding importKey takes the key in the DER format.
I have generated a key and certificate using the following command:
openssl req -newkey rsa-pss -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096 -sigopt rsa_pss_saltlen:32 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem

This creates a pkcs8 formatted private key. When using any private keys generated by this command, i receive this error DataError: Invalid key type.
This is the code used to import the key.
    const privateKey = await fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'certificates', 'key.pem'), 'utf-8');
    const pemHeader = '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----';
    const pemFooter = '-----END PRIVATE KEY-----';
    const pemContents = privateKey.substring(pemHeader.length, privateKey.length - pemFooter.length - 1);
    const key = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
      'pkcs8',
      Buffer.from(pemContents, 'base64'),
      { name: 'RSA-PSS', hash: { name: 'SHA-256' } },
      false,
      ['sign'],
    );

When using another key that I created using an online tool here, the key import works perfectly.
The command to generate they keys was provided by an API specifications document.
Could it be that I'm generating the key in a wrong way?

importKey() doesn't support OID 1.2.840.113549.1.1.10 (rsaPSS), only the more general OID 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1 (rsaEncryption). You must therefore generate the key accordingly from the start (as suggested in the answer) or you can adapt an existing rsaPSS key for importing with WebCrypto (for this, only the last byte of the OID 0x06092A864886F70D01010A must be adjusted from 0x0A to 0x01, e.g. in a hex editor).

It seems your library doesn't support PKCS#1 v2.1 key format. You should fallback to PKCS#1 v1.5 format as follows:
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem


I think your command will generate a traditional RSA private key, the specifications for the API i'm communicating with requires a RSA-PSS key.
"The certificate for registration with DIP and implicitly also the public/private keys must be generated using the RSA-PSS algorithm.".
Apparently there is no such as an "RSA-PSS" private key, it's basically using an RSA key to sign a sign something using RSA-PSS signing scheme. I will do some more research in the meantime.

@AlaaEddineCherif: Yes and no, one can argue there is no such thing as an RSA-PSS key but the storage format used to store the private key, PKCS8, has a field used to identify the key using something in ASN.1 called an object identifier. With your openssl req command, the object identifier in the PKCS8 private key file says the private key is an rsa-pss key rather than an rsa key. Just to see if it matters, you should try the command in this answer and see if your error goes away.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk The key import is successful, for now I'll continue using the Key generated by the command in this answer. I will however wait to mark an answer until I start communicating with the API, as they require an RSA-PSS key, and maybe will not accept the signature. If that happens I will try what Topaco mentioned in their comment. Thanks!

Finally, the RSA key was not accepted by the API. I ended up using a python script with PyJwt that allows the import of an RSA-PSS key. Thanks for the help :D
